# :not(:last-child) not working with label-wrapped list item

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

A quick CSS question. I have some list items with check boxes and I want to make the whole item clickable. Easy enough...just wrap it in the label for the check box. This works. Here are my two issues (I'm putting them both here because I think they might be caused by the same thing).

**Problem:** I'm trying to use :not(:last-child) to put divider lines between each of the list items (except for the last one) and I'm having trouble.

[**Here's a jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rEGex/4/)

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="box50">
    <div class="filterFolder">Companies<i class="icon-caret-down"></i></div>
    <ul id="companies">
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value" /> Apple</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value" /> Microsoft</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value" /> Google</label></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="filterFolder">People<i class="icon-caret-down"></i></div>
    <ul id="people">
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value" /> Mark Zuckerberg</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value" /> Steve Jobs</label></li>
        <li><label>><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value" /> Bill Gates</label></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="filterFolder">(+) Add New</div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    font-size:12px;
    padding:2px 7px;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #EFEFEF; 
}
    ul li:hover {
        background:#EFEFEF;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .listSelected {
        background:red;
    }
```

Comment: This really should be 2 different questions, as some people might be able to answer one but not the other.

Comment: I'll piece them out now. Thanks.

Comment: As a note: This is invalid HTML. Within `<ul>` you can't put `<label>`. You have to put it inside of `<li>`.

Comment: try adding jQuery to your fiddle

Comment: Hmm. Chrome must just know how to render it. I thought it might be when I wrote it, but I tried anyway and it worked. Adding the label inside only makes the text clickable...not the whole list item. I guess I'll just have to do some JS to fix it. @wirey, added. Woops. But that doesn't fix it, unfortunately.

Comment: Your fiddle is called `regex`. Interesting.

Comment: Hah, didn't even notice. Odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two separate issues.

The first issue is due to the fact that your html is invalid.  Only `li` can be children of `ul`.  `label` is not a valid child.  The solution is simple enough: wrap the `<label>` in the `<li>` rather than the opposite and change your style rules accordingly.

Your second issue is due to a bit of weird behavior caused by the label's default action of the input being checked causing the click event on the label to fire again (i.e. twice).  I can't explain this, but a simple solution is to check whether the input is checked or not to determine whether you should add the class because the "checking" happens before the second firing of `click`.

```
if ($(this).find('input').prop('checked')) {
    $(this).addClass("listSelected");
}
else {
    $(this).removeClass("listSelected");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/GFcvf/

Comment: Ahhh interesting. I didn't even think that the label might be capturing the click. I'll try this out. Looks like it works fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it like this:

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value"> Apple
    </label>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
ul label {
    display: block;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}

ul li:last-child label {
    border:none;
}
```

This is valid HTML and the whole `<li>` seems to be clickable - actually you're still clicking the `<label>`.

Another note: For inserting an icon use a `<span>` instead of `<i>` as a span ha no semantic meaning and the only purpose to add style.

Comment: I used an <i> because that's how they suggest using it on the FontAwesome site. I guess because <i> was deprecated with <em>? http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration

Comment: Strange - actually this is not the right usage for the `<i>` thingy. :) Anyway. Hope the rest was useful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest few minor changes.

1. Make the label `display: block` so that it stretches all the way across the LI. That way the label will intercept clicks anywhere inside the LI.
2. Attach a click handler to the checkbox itself (the above will facilitate this). Upon click, use `jQuery.closest()` to find the corresponding LI and apply CSS on it.
3. The `li:not(:last-child)` seems to work i.e. selects all LI except the one which is the last child.

This hopefully answers all 3 of your questions.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/rEGex/7/)

Comment: display:block worked perfectly. Thanks, Salman! You've answered quite a few of my questions over the past year, haha.